# Create Gstreamer pipeline send audio Mulaw encode via UDP host and port

Tags: android, c, gstreamer, mu-law

I have to send audio to the camera via the Android app, the camera uses Mulaw Encode, so I created a JNI C function Gstreamer to send the audio to the camera.
The sample pipeline I created:

> autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert !
> audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=8000,format=S16LE ! mulawenc ! udpsink
> host=xxxx port=xxxx

But it got a problem

> Internal data stream error. and  streaming stopped, reason
> not-negotiated (-4)

And cannot send audio to the camera. Could you guys show me what is the problem here?
My goal is to capture audio and convert it to "audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=8000,format=S16LE" then encode by Mulaw and send via UDP with host and port. It makes me stuck here too long.

Thank you very much for read.

Comment: Does adding `rtppcmupay` between mulawenc and udpsink help ?

Comment: @SeB Thank you. I tried, it's help but the sound sending is the clicking sound. Not my voice. Not sure if it relate to the audioresample or not.

Comment: That might be a clock rate issue, but I can't say more as I don't have your setup.